# UISlider remove right side of slider

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i want to remove the right side of UISlider, i tried to do it with :

```
[progressSlider setMaximumTrackImage:[[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but i remove all the slider and keep only the Thumb Image.
any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to provide it a simple transparent image instead?

Comment: You're welcome. I added it as an answer, it might help someone else, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *feed* it with a simple transparent image instead of autoreleased `UIImage` with no content.